# create multiple counts in one SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I would like to get the number of users per airline per end of each month of one year. Sadly I am only able to get the result per one month. Is it somehow possible to get a table with multiple counts per month in such a way that I don't have to do it all one by one?

That's the query I have for one month:

```
SELECT  
    COUNT (ID) as Counts, 
    AirlineCode   
FROM [liveDB].[dbo].[AppUser]   
WHERE CreateDate<'2016-10-30'
GROUP BY AirlineCode
```

Thanks a lot
Andreas

Comment: Your current query is grouping by the airlinecode - not by passenger. Add some sample data, and your table structure. Use the following as a guide: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: mysql  or sql-server ????  is not the same

Comment: @scaisEdge I think Stack Overflow's auto-tagger is really bad at these things.

Comment: @tadman  I agree with you .. tags are always added unnecessarily

Comment: @scaisEdge Other hypothesis is people think it's the "Mycrosoft SQL Server".

Comment: @tadman   mycrosoft sql server nice definition bravo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the month to the select and group by.

```
SELECT  
    COUNT (ID) as Counts, 
    ,TheMonth = datepart(month,CreateDate)
   , AirlineCode   
FROM [liveDB].[dbo].[AppUser]   
WHERE CreateDate<'2016-10-30'
GROUP BY AirlineCode, datepart(month,CreateDate)
```